# c++ Segmentation Fault for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, segmentation-fault

I am getting a segmentation fault in the following code:

```
   Node *pointerArray[6];
   int onesNeighbor[]={2,3,6};

   Node *createNode(int localDistance)//////creates a node
    {
Node *newNode;
newNode=new Node;
newNode->wasVisited=false;
newNode->shortestDistance=localDistance;


return newNode;
    }

    void insertNode(Node *n,int i)//////////////////connects nodes to the
    {/////////////////////////////////////////array of pointers
     pointerArray[i]=n;
    }


for(i=1;i<7;i++)
{
    if(i==1){
    n=createNode(0);
    cout<<i<<"\t"<<n->shortestDistance<<"\t";
    for(int j=0;j<=2;j++)
   cout<< onesNeighbor[j]<<",";
   cout<<endl;


    for (count = 1; count < 2; count++)
    {
     current = pointerArray[count];

    if (count == 1)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 2; j++)
        {
            lowest = current->shortestDistance;
            current = pointerArray[onesNeighbor[j]];

            if (current->shortestDistance < lowest)
            {
                lowest = current->shortestDistance;
                closestNeighbor = onesNeighbor[j];
            }
        }
       }
      }
```

PLease Help.....

Comment: what line is it the segment fault happening?

Comment: We'd need to see the declarations of `pointerArray` and `onesNeighbor` to be able to tell you exactly, but basically, one of those arrays is either too small, or a wild pointer -- probably the latter.

Comment: COde as currently written will never reach the inner loop, since count will be 2 at the start of the first iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a completely blind guess, without the declarations of the 2 arrays, caused by an off by one error addressing them.  Either `j<=2` should be `j<2` and/or `count=1` should be `count=0`.  Just my attempt at psychic debugging.

Update: New version is not much clearer - you like to leave way too much to the imagination.  There are no calls to insertNode, so any attempt to deref pointerArray may seg-fault.  Is that a typo in the question, or the cause of the seg-fault you're seeing?  Also, the outermost loop iterates from 1 to 7 - is that supposed to correspond to the pointerArray?  If so, 0 - 6 might make more sense if you're going to call insertNode passing i as the second param.  Do you have code that compiles?